# Find an algorithm for two meetings occuring at the same time problem

Tags: algorithm, math

I have to solve a simple meeting problem, but i cannot find the right keywords to find a correct mathematic description of the problem i'm trying to solve. Maybe someone can help me there:

**The problem:**

A number of participants have to meet with each other:
Exemple:
A have to meet with B and C (ABC)
P have to meet with O and R (POR)
A have to meet with D and P (ADP)
X have to meet with Y and Z (XYZ)
Z have to meet with O and I (ZOI)
J have to meet with S and X (JSX)

**The constraint is the following: two meetings are occuring at the same time. One person cannot attend two meeting at the same time.**

I have to find a solution for scheduling the meetings:
Week 1: ABC (Room 1) - POR (Room 2)
Week 2: ADP (Room 1) - XYZ (Room 2)
Week 3: ZOI (Room 1) - JSX (Room 2)
Is a solution

Week 1: ABC (Room 1) - ADP (Room 2)
This is impossible because A have to be at two meetings at the same time.

This exemple is fairly simple, but of course the number of meetings is a lot bigger in the case i waana solve, hence, trying to find an algorithm to solve it in a relevant time.

Can someone provide a reference to or an algorithm, or the name of the problem?
Doesn't look like 'Maximum Bipartite Matching' or 'Bin packing'.

Comment: Is the room number important somehow?

Comment: And meetings don't have beginning or end times? It's just "The same person cannot be in two meetings scheduled during the same week?"

Comment: @Edward Peters
 In the case there are two different rooms. Room number is not important.
Both meetings start and end at the same time. And there only two meetings per iteration (here, two meetings a week in the exemple provided).

Comment: Okay, so you just need to count how many meetings each person is in each week, and if that number if ever more than one, it's impossible. The time complexity on that is only equal to the number of assignments, so you're doing that much work just to read the input.

Comment: @Edward Peters
Oh I didn't thought about that. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think it isn't a maximum bipartite matching?

Let's say a node is a set of people who need to meet together. Draw an edge between every pair of nodes that are compatible (have no people in common).

In your example, nodes are:

```
0 ABC
1 POR
2 ADP
3 XYZ
4 ZOI
5 JSX
```

And edges are: (0,1), (0,3), (0,4), (0,5), (1,3), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (4,5).

Then the nodes at each end of each edge of a matching are compatible (can meet at the same time). A maximum matching will give you the max number of concurrent pairs of meetings, and if a solution is possible will include all nodes.